# Combining and with or conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I stuck with a query which has to combine some conditions.

this properties of the catalog are the following

- _id:integer
- parentID: integer
- path: string
- level: integer

i have absolutely no clue how to combine them, so that the query returns what I need.

- a) _id has to be one of a given list (`"_id": ["7","10"]`) OR
- b) parentID has to be of a given integer (`"_parentID": "1"`) OR
- c) path has to match a special pattern (`"regexp": {"path": "/foobar.*"}`) AND level has be between two integer (`"range": {"level": {"gte": 2, "lte": 3 } }`)

Additionaly all entries have to be from one defined catalog

I will not write down all my attempts. I tried to use bool query with must and should, but this does not apply c):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "type": {
                "value": "category"
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "regexp": {
                "path": "/foobar.*"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "level": {
                  "gte": 2,
                  "lte": 3
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "_id": [
                  "7",
                  "10"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what is the best way to combine and and or conditions? i am kind of lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be pretty darn close to what you need.

```
GET devdev/alert/_search
{
    "filter": {
        "or": {
           "filters": [
              {
                   "terms": {
                      "_id": [
                         "eee75eJpRua4HasVzz0PeA",
                         "VALUE2"
                      ]
                   }
              },
              {
               "term": {
                  "_parentID": "SE.SE.0000"
               }   
              },
              {
               "and": {
                     "filters": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                               "regexp": "foobar"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                         "range": {
                            "level": {
                               "from":  2,
                               "to": 3
                            }
                         }   
                        }
                     ]
                  }   
              }
           ]
        }
    }
}
```